# VBA Listbox - Selection Text Issue

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Would there be anyone out there that could point me in the right direction with a system I am making within vba (excel based).

I currently have a userform with a multi col listbox selection, the listbox is populated from the database. But when you go to select the item on the listbox it only shows the first col. How would I be able to make it so it showed the first and seconded col. Please see below images

[image: Listbox when open]

[image: Listbox when selected]

```
form_create_order.Controls("cmb_product_category").Enabled = True

Dim Connection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst     As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rcArray As Variant
Dim sSQL    As String

With Connection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = DatabaseLocation
    .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = ProtectPassword
    .Open
End With

sSQL = "SELECT ID, Category_Name " & _
    "FROM Category_Database ORDER BY Category_Name;"

rst.Open sSQL, Connection
rcArray = rst.GetRows

With form_create_order.cmb_product_category
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .List = Application.Transpose(rcArray)
    .ListIndex = -1
End With

rst.Close
Connection.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set Connection = Nothing
```

Comment: There's a `ColumnWiths` property. You can set column(0)=0 to hide this column and display only description.

Comment: Thnk you that solved my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Liam, please accept my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to follow the MSDN documentation: [How to: Change the Column Widths of a Multi-Column List Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/general/how-to-change-the-column-widths-of-a-multi-column-list-box)

```
ListBox1.ColumnWidths="0;500" 'replace `;` with `,` if your system uses commas as a separator
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Accordingly to [PEH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%e1%b4%87%ca%9c) comment, you can use:

```
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = Replace$("0;500", ";", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
```

if you're looking for more flexible solution, independent of regional settings.

Comment: Use `ListBox1.ColumnWidths = Replace$("0;500", ";", Application.International(xlListSeparator))` and it is always correct no matter what the user has set in his operating system.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thank you for your valuable comment. This is very useful when it is used with VBA code. My fist thought was to provide a way how to achieve that without VBA code. Cheers, Maciej

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of giving alternatives (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574467/how-to-display-second-column-in-combobox-after-selection)):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

With ComboBox1
    .Text = .List(.ListIndex, 0) & " | " & .List(.ListIndex, 1)
End With

End Sub
```

No need for columnwidth in this case (however, that is a more elegant way).

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a more elegant solution. It is opinion based only. In my opinion, end user don't have to know what category has got what number. But... this is my opinion ;)